# How to create Material UI Dialog with transparent background color?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a loading status indicator using Material UI. But I want the background color of the dialogue box as `none` and also want to adjust the height. But I'm not able to do it with the style option provided by them. Any solution?

[Now it looks like this..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1k8X.png)

[image: 1]

Code looks like this:

```
<Dialog
  open={true}
  style={{width: '200px', marginLeft: '40%', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
  title= 'Loading'
  titleStyle={{paddingTop: '0px', paddingLeft: '45px', fontSize: '15px', lineHeight: '40px'}}
>
    <RefreshIndicator
      style= {{display: 'inline-block'}}
      size={50}
      left={50}
      top={30}
      loadingColor="#FF9800"
      status="loading"    
    />
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 59):

For the latest version (`"@material-ui/core": "^1.2.3"`), here is how it's done:

```
<Dialog
  {...otherProps}
  PaperProps={{
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      boxShadow: 'none',
    },
  }}
>
  {/* ... your content ... */}
</Dialog>
```

Take note of the new `PaperProps` prop. It's not in the documentation but if you check out the source, they are using `PaperProps` as one of the props you can pass in - since this isn't in the docs, this might change with future versions though, so be careful here.

Comment: PaperProps are documented in Dialog API page: https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/

Comment: For Modal, use `BackdropProps` instead of `PaperProps`, works just fine.

Answer (score 22):

In Material UI v4 or latest. You can use `BackdropProps`, see the [online demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-8imr3)

Comment: This helped me, thx.
Its a syntax sheme working for all nested Components:
https://material-ui.com/guides/api/#nested-components

What also works is: BackdropProps={{invisible: true}}

Comment: this is the best answer now

Answer (score 9):

You can set the overlayStyle prop on Dialog to change the background color, like so:

```
 <Dialog
  open={true}
  style={{width: '200px', marginLeft: '40%', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
  overlayStyle={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
  title= 'Loading'
  titleStyle={{paddingTop: '0px', paddingLeft: '45px', fontSize: '15px', lineHeight: '40px'}}
  >
```

Comment: `overlayStyle={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}` did the trick... Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Directly you can use `CircularProgress` with css properties, `zIndex` and `opacity`, Try this:

```
<CircularProgress size={2} style={Styles.mainLoader}/>

mainLoader: { 
    position: 'absolute',
    paddingTop: '15%',      
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    zIndex: 1000,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    opacity: 0.5,
    textAlign: 'center',
}
```

It will cover the entire screen with .5 opacity and specified background.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use a transparent `Dialog`, Material UI exposes the [`Backdrop`](https://mui.com/components/backdrop/#main-content) component which `Dialog` uses behind the scene. `Backdrop` lets you put any content inside a dimmed layer without having to deal with the physical container:

```
<Backdrop
  sx={{ color: '#fff', zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }}
  open={open}
  onClick={handleClose}
>
  <Stack gap={1} justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
    <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
    <Typography>Loading...</Typography>
  </Stack>
</Backdrop>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 2):

Use the bodyStyle props like so:

```
<Dialog
  bodyStyle={{margin:0, padding:0}}
  open={true}
  style={{width: '200px', marginLeft: '40%', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
  title= 'Loading'
  titleStyle={{paddingTop: '0px', paddingLeft: '45px', fontSize: '15px', lineHeight: '40px'}}
>
    <RefreshIndicator
      style= {{display: 'inline-block'}}
      size={50}
      left={50}
      top={30}
      loadingColor="#FF9800"
      status="loading"    
    />
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Dialog
  open={true}
  style={{width: '200px', marginLeft: '40%', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
  title= 'Loading'
  titleStyle={{paddingTop: '0px', paddingLeft: '45px', fontSize: '15px', lineHeight: '40px'}}
BackdropProps={{invisible: true}}
>
    <RefreshIndicator
      style= {{display: 'inline-block'}}
      size={50}
      left={50}
      top={30}
      loadingColor="#FF9800"
      status="loading"    
    />
</Dialog>
```

- List item

Remove backgroundColor: 'transparent' and add BackdropProps={{invisible: true}}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is the component `CircularProgress` which you can use directly (instead of building a loding indicator by using `Dialog`: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/circular-progress

You can place the loading indicator in a `div` which is placed in the middle of the page:

JSX:

```
<div className="my-spinner">
    <CircularProgress size={59.5} />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-spinner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another potential alternative for this (depends on what you want to achieve) is to avoid using a `Paper` component for the `Dialog` container. For example, if you use a `Box` component instead, it won't be visible to the user:

```
<Dialog
  className="MyDialog"
  open={!!openProp}
  onClose={handleDialogClose}
  maxWidth="xl"
  PaperComponent={Box}
>
```

Note that by default it will still contain an 'invisible' padding (or even cover most of the screen if you use the `fullWidth` prop), and this can be confusing for users, since the Dialog won't get closed when clicking within this invisible component.

Answer (score 0):

you can change in MUI v5 like this

```
<Dialog
    onClose={handleClose}
    open={open}
    slotProps={{ backdrop: { sx: { background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)' } } }}
  >
     {/* CONTENT */}
  </Dialog>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [BackgropProps](https://mui.com/api/modal/#props)

Whether you could use [Modal](https://mui.com/components/modal/#main-content) itself which is a low-level component of [Dialog](https://mui.com/components/dialogs/#main-content) or you could stick to Dialog it's will work for both.

```
<Modal BackdropProps={{ style: { backgroundColor: "green" } }} ></Modal>
```

```
<Dialog BackdropProps={{ style: { backgroundColor: "green" } }} ></Dialog>
```

Comment: backdropProps is actually deprecated